# What's the most common name for the owner of the apartment (in which rents it to others)

Tags: word-usage, word-request, british-english

What's the most common name -in the UK- for the owner of the apartment (in which rents it to others)?

I found three choices: **homeowner, landlord, owner**. Is one of them is more common in usage than the other?

Answer (score 2):

Landlord is the correct term when the apartment is rented to others.

This can be via a letting agency or a direct relationship between both parties.

Answer (score 1):

The landlord lets the apartment to the tenant.

The tenant rents the apartment from the landlord.

The landlord is not always the owner of the apartment. Sometimes a council (local authority) or university will lease apartments from the owners on a long-term lease and then let them to tenants for shorter periods.